# Animating when filtering divs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I can't quite wrap my head around how to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

I have a search field and as you type into it, it is looking at a data-attribute and hiding the divs that don't have the correct data. I would like to fade out the divs that don't have the correct data. I'd also like them to fade in as you clear out the search box. I can't quite figure out what I need to do, should I use .fadeIn/.fadeOut or should I be adding/removing classes?

This is my code for the filtering:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
    var selectSize = $(this).val();
    filter(selectSize);
});

function filter(e) {
    if(e) {
        var regex = new RegExp('\\b\\w*' + e + '\\w*\\b', 'i');
        $('.oneStaff').hide().filter(function () {
            return regex.test($(this).data('regions'))
        }).show();
    } else {
        $('.oneStaff').show();
      }
}
```

Comment: As I recall `show/hide` uses the `display` property **which cannot be animated**. FadeIn would seem to be the optimal solution.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for the comment. It sent me in the right direction. I used fadeIn/fadeOut and it worked like a charm.